# java8 stream style for retrieving a inner part of map through a field list?

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

For example, given a map like below:

```
{
  "k1": {
    "k2": {
      "k3": {
        "k4": "v"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and a field list `["k1","k2","k3"]`, I need to retrieve the part `{"k4": "v"}`.

Below is my java7-style code:

```
// Ignore the map building code.
Map map1 = new HashMap();
Map map2 = new HashMap();
Map map3 = new HashMap();
Map map4 = new HashMap();
map4.put("k4", "v");
map3.put("k3", map4);
map2.put("k2", map3);
map1.put("k1", map2);
Map map = map1;
System.out.println(map); //=> {k1={k2={k3={k4=v}}}}

// Code to be transformed to java8 style
List<String> fields = Arrays.asList("k1", "k2", "k3");
for(String field: fields) {
    map = (Map) map.get(field);
}
System.out.println(map); //=> {k4=v}
```

Then how to transform above code to java 8 stream style?

Answer (score 8):

I don’t think that there is any benefit in converting this into a functional style; the loop is fine and precisely expresses what you are doing.

But for completeness, you can do it the following way:

```
map = (Map)fields.stream()
    .<Function>map(key -> m -> ((Map)m).get(key))
    .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen).apply(map);
```

This converts each key to a function capable of doing a map lookup of that key, then composes them to a single function that is applied to you `map`. Postponing the operation to that point is necessary as functions are not allowed to modify local variables.

It’s also possible to fuse the `map` operation with the `reduce` operation, which allows to omit the explicit type (`<Function>`):

```
map = (Map)fields.parallelStream()
 .reduce(Function.identity(), (f, key)->f.andThen(m->((Map)m).get(key)), Function::andThen)
 .apply(map);
```

Maybe you recognize now, that this is a task for which a simple `for` loop is better suited.

Comment: @tobias_k: this works perfectly in parallel, as turning the stream to parallel would only parallelize the function composition, whereas the final `apply` call is always sequential (and independent from the stream).

Comment: @Holger your answers make me dizzy. this is very nice

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
fields.stream().reduce(map1, (m, key) -> (Map) m.get(key), (a, b) -> a);
```