# Collect/reduce on a stream when no combine function exists

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a collection where I would like to use the stream API to reduce it to a single value.  It looks like `collect` or `reduce` would work well, except that both of them want a `combiner` object to merge parallel results.  In my case, I do not have a combining operation.

There will not be a lot of elements in the stream, so I am happy to have it run serially.  Is there a way to handle this?

If my stream contains 1,2 and 3, I want to do the equivalent of

```
result = new Foo().foo(1).foo(2).foo(3);
```

It seems that

```
result = stream.reduce(new Foo(),
                       (foo, ele) -> foo.foo(ele),
                       null);
```

would likely work, but at some point, some change (slightly longer list, new Java version) the `combiner` will get called and that will break.

I am returning a different type, so `reduce(BiFunction)` will not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java8 stream style for retrieving a inner part of map through a field list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278737/java8-stream-style-for-retrieving-a-inner-part-of-map-through-a-field-list)

Comment: If you're concerned about being at the whim and mercy of the stream API to use the combiner, why not just use a plain loop?

Comment: @shmosel  That does look it would solve the problem.  Although it also looks a bit complicated, like it is trying to solve a problem introduced by the language.

Comment: @AndyTurner I could do that, although I am currently drinking the Kool-Aid that says that functional/streams is better than procedural/for loops.  I think that often, it is easier to read.  On a different project, I use an alternate library (javaslang) which does not have automatic parallelization, and as a result, it has a reduce(initialElement, combiner) method, which does what I need.

Comment: @TroyDaniels I've added an answer showing how simple it is in non-streams Java. Sometimes you've got to know when to put the kool aid down ;)

Comment: There are several ways to solve this, but none of them looks simpler than a `for` loop. Which, of course, is related to the point that even `result = stream.reduce(new Foo(), (foo, ele) -> foo.foo(ele), null);` is not simpler than a straight-forward loop and adding a fix doesn’t make it simpler… By the way, streams reject `null` combiners even if they don’t use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a loop over the elements of the collection:

```
Foo result = new Foo();
for (int ele : collection) {
  result = result.foo(ele);
}
```

This is easy to read, of similar verbosity to the streams approach, and you don't have to worry about its behaviour changing unexpectedly because of dark voodoo in the Streams library.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to stick to a stream, you could use `forEachOrdered` as it is allowed to be stateful:

```
AtomicReference<Foo> foo = new AtomicReference<>(new Foo());
stream.forEachOrdered(ele -> foo.updateAndGet(f -> f.foo(ele)));        
Foo result = foo.get();
```